# Tor Browser Data Files

Tags: configuration

I want to know what the difference between the torrc file & the torrc-defaults file is, seeing in the verbose output it says both are read when I start my browser.

I also want to know the purpose of the hidden file .torrc.swp especially seeing it is not human readable.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tor reads and uses torrc.  Let's say you delete it or you really screw something up in it. You copy the torrc-defaults to torrc and start fresh from scratch. This is very common in the Linux world. It is -defaults because it is the default configuration.

.torrc.swp has nothing to do with tor. If you open the file with vim, then vim creates as a temp file. When you close vim, then it should be deleted automatically. If you have more question about vim, then ask in Unix/Linux.

Comment: haha yes I'm sure those people will be very happy to hear from me again so what you are saying, is I can delete the swap file without disruption to tor's function? and my torrc and torrc-defaults have **very** different content. and the verbose that accompanies me opening the browser definitely states that both are read. I am pretty much a Linux virgin fyi so be nice